# select doesn't show selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for both the new and edit action. one of the fields is a selectbox and when editing the select should show the value from the database. This is what I have now, but it shows "basic" as value, not "premium" (which is stored as database value):

```
<%= s_form.select(:name, 
                  options_for_select([['Basic', 'basic'], ['Premium', 'premium']]), 
                  :selected => params[:name]) %>
```

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass the selected option to the [option_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) helper like:

```
<%= s_form.select(:name, options_for_select([['Basic', 'basic'], ['Premium', 'premium']], :selected => params[:name])) %>
```

Comment: If I use the hard coded value it does work: ":selected => 'premium'"

Comment: It should. What does param[:name] contain?

Comment: Yep.. So the problem is the param I guess.

Comment: This is really strange. Are you sure your params[:name] holds exactly "premium"? Because I've tested it and it works just fine.