# form_for with f.select and options_for_select works for one attribute but not the second

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

This seems like a really basic questions, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have my rails form_for with select and options_for_select.

The :plan attribute gets created correctly based on what's selected, but for the plan attribute it's always "1st year" no matter what you select for create and when trying to edit. They're basically identical, so I don't understand why one works and not the other. Thanks in advance for your help!

Create Form:

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :phone %>
<%= f.text_field :phone %>
<%= f.label :year %>
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select([['1st Year', 1], ['2nd Year', 2], ['3rd Year', 3], ['4th Year', 4]]) %>
<%= f.label :plan %>
<%= f.select :plan, options_for_select([['15', 15], ['45', 45], ['75', 75], ['105', 105]]) %>
<%= f.submit%>
<%end%>
```

Edit Form:

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :phone %>
<%= f.text_field :phone %>
<%= f.label :year %>
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select([['1st Year', 1], ['2nd Year', 2], ['3rd Year', 3], ['4th Year', 4]]) %>
<% if current_user.role == "admin"%>
<%= f.label :plan %>
<%= f.text_field :plan %>
<%else%>
<p>Plan selected: <%=@customer.plan%></p>
<%end%>

<%= f.submit%>
<%end%>
```

customer_controller:

```
def create
    @customer = current_user.customers.create(customer_params)
    if current_user.role == "admin"
      redirect_to customers_path
    elsif current_user.role == "customer"
      redirect_to user_customer_path(current_user, @customer)
    else
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end

  def update
    @customer.update(customer_params)
    if current_user.role === "customer"
      redirect_to customer_path(@customer)
    else
      redirect_to customers_path
    end
  end

private
  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:name,:year,:email,:plan,:verification)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I checked my rails console and saw that it was actually working! This meant that the issue was with what was selected. I found the solution in the comments on this: [select doesn't show selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374889/select-doesnt-show-selected-value)

and was able to get it to show the correct selected value with the code below:

```
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select([['1st Year', 1.to_i], ['2nd Year', 2.to_i], ['3rd Year', 3], ['4th Year', 4]], selected: @customer.year) %>
```